# why am I getting only 2 and 3 as false? (returns true if number is prime)

Tags: javascript, function

I'll start off by saying that I am terrible when it comes to numbers. Anyways, I'm writing a function 'testPrime' that accepts a # as a parameter and returns true if the number is prime or false if it ain't.

Code:

```
function testPrime(n) {

 if (n % 2 !== 0 && n % 3 !== 0) {
    return true; 
 } else { 
    return false;
  }
};
```

So I'm not too sure if this right (am I?) but when I tested out a gazillion numbers on console by typing in testPrime(insert number here), it seems like only 2 and 3 are getting returned as false, when they should be getting returned as true. (2 and 3 are prime ... right?) Did I leave something out in my if statement? Can't seem to find the issue. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try one of these http://www.javascripter.net/faq/numberisprime.htm

Comment: There are lots of problems here. It will return `false` for any multiple of 2 or 3, such as 6. And it will return `false` for `2` and for `3` because you don't allow for those possibilities. Besides, you don't deal with non-primes that aren't multiples of 2 or 3. What about 25, for example? You need to rethink your approach to this. (Hint: you need a loop.)

Comment: further hint: you need to know what a prime number actually is

Comment: Another question is -- why? If it's for a school project, then doing it the complete way is fine. For a performance critical project though, it's probably better to pre-compute the first X primes. If n is below the last value you checked when you did your offline calculation, but positive and an integer, then loop through the list. If it's there? It's prime. Else, it's composite. You should then only directly calculate numbers that are larger than your pre-computed table's end value at runtime (unless you know that large primes are semi-guaranteed ex: encryption).

Answer (score 3):

Hello you are dividing number only by 2 and 3 that is not a proper way to find a prime number. as there are numbers which are divisible only by prime numbers. for example you 49 is not a prime number as it is divisible by 7 only. so we have to consider all the prime number less than half the input number. you can have a look in following code for reference. it'll check if the number is prime or not.

```js
var n = 29;
var flag = true;
for(var i=2; i<n/2;i++){
  if(n%i == 0){
    flag = false;
    break;
  }
}
var docElem = document.getElementById("test");
if(flag){
  docElem.innerHTML = n + " is Prime number";
}else{
  docElem.innerHTML = n + " is not a Prime number";
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the given code you tested prime only for 2 and 3. So if n=25 than your program return true even though 25 is not a prime number , because 25 will be checked for only 2 and 3 not 5.

You should write your code as follow by adding a loop:

```
for (i=2 ; i<n ;)
if (n%i == 0) {
    return false;
    i++; 
    } 
    else { 
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: You can save a bit of time by only searching up to the square root of n, since any larger number would need to be multiplied by a smaller number (and thus already checked).

Comment: This program is to check prime numbers not to check or find root or square.

Comment: Scott is suggesting an optimisation, not a change in purpose. You can also skip all even numbers once 2 has been tested.

Comment: Correct. It checks prime numbers, but you don't need to check every number less than n to see if it is a factor. It is sufficient to stop at sqrt(n) because any LARGER number must be multiplied with a smaller number. Ex: Root 10 is 3.16. 10's factor tree is 1, 2, 5, 10. It is sufficient to check just 2 and 3, because 4 * at least 4 = 16 or higher, 5 * at least 5 = 25 or higher, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Uh...I have way too much time on my hands.  Anyway, I'd probably go ahead and collect the numbers the item is divisible by, though this adds lots of extra calculation(If you just want prime, you can stop after the first).

html:

```
<div class="primeTest">
    <label>Enter a number</label><input type='text' id="number" class="input"/>
    <div class="results"></div>
    <div class="divisibleBy"></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var test = function(n){
    var max = Math.sqrt(n),
        t = 2,
        divBy = [],
        str;
    if (!(n > 1 && n < 4)) {
        while (t <= max) {
            if (n % t === 0) divBy.push([t,n/t]);
            t++;
        }
    }
    if (divBy.length) {
        var str = '';
        divBy.forEach( function(d){
            str += '<div>' + d[0] + ' * ' + d[1] + '</div>';
        });
        $('.results').html( n + ' is NOT a prime number.');
        $('.divisibleBy').html( 'It is a product of each of the following:' + str );
    } else {
    $('.results')
        .html(n + ' IS a prime number.')
        .addClass('prime');
    }
}
$('.input').keyup(function() { test( this.value ) });
```

And here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/upvjuh51/3/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use recursion,
Try with this function:

```
var x = 2;
function testPrime(n) {
 if(n == x){
    return true;
 }
 else if((n > x) && (n%x == 0) ){
   return false;
 }
 else if((n > x) && (n%x != 0)){
   x++;
   testPrime(n);
 }
}
```